# XML to Bean mapping : XML element value to Bean setter mapper

Tags: java, xml, javabeans, xmlmapper

XML element value to Bean setter mapper :

I have a XML file and set of Beans. I want to populate XML values in set of Beans through a mapper. 
Normally, When we are writing XML parsing & populating value in beans, we manually map XML element value to Bean setter.

I am looking for a tool, which provide UI to map XML element value to a Bean setter using drag & drop and this tool should provide mapper for XML to Bean mapping.

Please could any one guide me on this or share your knowledge on this.

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse Juno for Java EE Developers](http://eclipse.org/downloads/) includes the [Dali plug-in](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/) (part of Web Tools Project) which provides mapping assistance for mapping beans to an XML schema.  The mapping isn't drag and drop, but it displays validation messages where your mapping does not match the XML schema and provides code assist for creating the necessary JAXB mappings.

Answer (score 0):

I did a benchamark time ago about read/write XML. It was StAX, JAXB + StAX, JAXB, Apache XML Beans.

I can say to you that the winner was Apache XML Beans and with difference between the others. So I can not say to you a UI to work with it, but with Apache XML Beans just give the XSD and your classes will be create on package (jar) or on folder.

I expect it will help to you to take a decision.

Comment: thanks Javier for your input, but I am looking for a tool, which provide UI to map XML element value to a Bean setter using drag & drop and this tool should provide mapper for XML to Bean mapping.

Comment: I don't understand why need a tool using drag&drop if can generate it automatically.
Post generate, also you will be able to map XML to Bean or Bean to XML just with Apache XML Beans automatically.